# How to create group box

Tags: javascript, html

I have found this code for creating group box :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

It is said that it creates the following group box at runtime:
[image]

When I run in my Visual Studio Code it appears like this:
[image]

The border is hardly visible and the text appears in a wrong place. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: These are predefined styles of your browser. You can customize them with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CSS to your element:

```
border: 5px solid black;
```

Example:

```html
<fieldset style="border: 5px solid black;">
    <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I didn't mean border - I meant the look and feel of the group box is not correct.

Comment: You can customize the CSS like any other HTML element;  consider researching CSS for more info regarding how to style the element to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that all browsers have different default styling. Yours is unusual.

I copied some of my User Agent Stylesheets from MacOS+Chrome109

```css
fieldset {
    display: block;
    margin-inline-start: 2px;
    margin-inline-end: 2px;
    padding-block-start: 0.35em;
    padding-inline-start: 0.75em;
    padding-inline-end: 0.75em;
    padding-block-end: 0.625em;
    min-inline-size: min-content;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
    border-image: initial;
}

legend {
    display: block;
    padding-inline-start: 2px;
    padding-inline-end: 2px;
    border-width: initial;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It looks exactly like before. Title is inside the box - not on line